# How To Filter Nested JSON Data Without Nested Ranges

Tags: json, linux, bash, sed, jq

I have the following code and I'm trying to extract only the "numbers" using `jq`. I have researched various `jq` code examples.

I tried different variation of code:

`jq '.data | .numbers'`

and

`jq '.data | .numbers[1:3]'`

but I'm unable to get just the numbers.

```
{
    page_size: 3,
    data: {
        numbers: {
            +18459939294: {
                state: in_service,
                features: [e911, outbound_cnam, inbound_cnam],
                features_allowed: [],
                features_denied: [],
            },
            +12018986776: {
                state: in_service,
                features: [],
                features_allowed: [],
                features_denied: [],
            },
            +12120098763: {
                state: in_service,
                features: [],
                features_allowed: [],
                features_denied: [],
            }
        },
        casquade_quantity: 3
    },
    revision: 79807405987349087540983759804,
    timestamp: 2018 - 09 - 14T17: 07: 49,
    version: x.x.x,
    node: aojflksajflkmaMmiaonfsd,
    request_id: -098230-49823049-82309,
    status: success,
}
```

How can I get the output:

```
+18459939294
+12018986776
+12120098763
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON: your strings are not quoted, and you have extraneous commas

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help though Glenn. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numbers` is an object, not just a array of keys. Just get the (unsorted) keys from that object.

```
.data.numbers | keys_unsorted[]
```

You will probably want to get the raw output as well so be sure to add the `-r` switch.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Jeff. Works for me!